# PHP using preg_replace to replace same character to different tags

Tags: php, regex

in user text i have some star into that and i'm trying to convert them to `html` regular tags, for example, user text is :

> For every loop iteration, the ** value ** of the current ** array element ** is assigned to $value and ** the array pointer ** is moved by one, until it reaches the last array element.

as you see i have some words between stars such as `value`, `array element` and etc, now i want to convert first star to `<b>` and second star to `</b>`, then finally i should have:

```
For every loop iteration, the <b> value </b> of the current <b> array 
element </b> is assigned to $value and <b> the array pointer 
<b> is moved by one, until it reaches the last array element.
```

how can i find and convert them? Thanks

Comment: With code. Where's yours?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol if i know whats solution i pasted that into code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/3XuP2V/1

```
$re = '/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/';
$str = 'For every loop iteration, the ** value ** of the current ** array element ** is assigned to $value and ** the array pointer ** is moved by one, until it reaches the last array element.';
$subst = '<b>$1</b>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

`\*` will escape `*` to match it literally.
`(.*?)` is lazy match for anything of any lenght

Comment: how about `/* TEXT */`? regular as `'/\/\*(.*?)\/\*/'` and replace that to `'<r>$1</r>';` not working for me, problem is second `*/`

Comment: Maybe you need to place the * and / in the correct order? Your example is `*/` and pattern is `/*`